# Travis CI not using correct node.js version

Tags: node.js, testing, travis-ci

I'm writing ES6 code, using `class` and `const`, but Travis CI is saying that my build is failing because it is running my test script with `node.js` version `0.10.48`. Here is a link to the failed build: https://travis-ci.org/javacoolme/google-sign-in/builds/205586193.

Comment: can you please post your .yml configuration file?

Comment: @ex0dm3nt It's on the GitHub repository, located [here](https://github.com/javacoolme/google-sign-in/blob/master/.travis.yml)

Comment: This link https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/javascript-with-nodejs/#Even-more-Nodejs-versions provides the list of node.js versions that can work without `nvm` having to install them. Could you try one of these versions?

Comment: @ex0dm3nt Nope, Travis is still using `0.10.48`

Comment: I think it might be a indentation issue. Make sure you only have 2 spaces before `- "6"` (updated my answer with that information)

Comment: @Canastro Nope :( Also, if you look at the config tab [here](https://travis-ci.org/javacoolme/google-sign-in/jobs/205599357/config) (in JSON) it shows that it has the correct version.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should specify the node versions you want to test in your .travis.yml file like this:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "6"
  - "4"
```

Make sure you have the correct indentation... Only 2 spaces before `- "6"`

Comment: I've seen you tried node_js 6, please put node 6 in the engines in package.json file

Comment: damm, still no luck. Never had this kind of issues :o

Comment: Yeah, I'm very confused also.

Comment: Try to put just "6", I never had set a specific version.

Comment: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/javascript-with-nodejs#Even-more-Nodejs-versions  As you can see here, they don't specify the minor version, maybe its related with that.

Comment: I'll try 6.1.x, 6, and 6.1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136705/discussion-between-bennett-and-canastro).

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the node version as described [here](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/javascript-with-nodejs).

Comment: I just updated it, but the build is still failing.
[Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/javacoolme/google-sign-in)
[.travis.yml](https://github.com/javacoolme/google-sign-in/blob/master/.travis.yml)
It also is still using version `0.10.48`.